# How to get a non-observable value from a function?

Tags: rx-swift

I have this function which doesn't work, because immediately returns without setting `data`

```swift
func fetchedData() -> String {
    var data: String
    networkRequest.suscribe(
        onNext: {
            data = "successful"
        },
        onError: {
            data = "unsuccesful"
    }).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
    return data
}
```

How can I make it work? Sorry I am fairly new to RxSwift

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will helps you.

```
func fetchedData(isSuccess: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
  networkRequest.suscribe(
    onNext: {
        isSuccess(true)
  },
    onError: {
        isSuccess(false)
  }).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}

fetchedData { (isSuccess) in
  if isSuccess {
    print("Successfull")
  } else {
    print("Unsuccessfull")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it seems, it should work. I'll report back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually what you are trying to achieve can be done with semaphores for example. But your approach is really bad, as I believe you misunderstood the concepts of `RxSwift` and reactive programming in general.

The first thing you need to understand is that everything in RxSwift is an observable sequence or something that operates on or subscribes to events emitted by an observable sequence.
`Arrays`, `Strings` or `Dictionaries` will be converted to observable sequences in `RxSwift`. You can create an observable sequence of any `Object` that conforms to the `Sequence Protocol` from the Swift Standard Library.

You should not use such function in your code `func fetchedData() -> String`. In your case you may want to use something like:

```
func fetchedData() -> Observable<String> {
    return networkRequest.map { _ -> String in
      return "Successfull"
    }.catchErrorJustReturn("Unsuccessfull")
}
```

Then you have your code aligned with reactive principles. You may bind this sequence to some variables, transform it, share and so on.